# How to define the exact starting point of a mechanistic arrow in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I want to draw a radical reaction mechanism and obviously the arrow should start at the lone electron and not at the corresponding atom. How could I achieve this?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
\setatomsep{2em}
\setdoublesep{.6ex}
\setbondstyle{semithick}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{myedge/.style={->, -{Latex[#1]}}}

\begin{document}

\section{B}

\schemestart
\chemfig{@{r1}\lewis{0.,Rad}}
\+
\chemfig{R^1(-[@{r2a}::125,,,,draw=none])(-[@{r2b}::145,,,,draw=none])-@{r4}C(-[@{r3}::90]H)(-[270]H)-O-R^2}
\schemestop

\chemmove[->,shorten <=2pt]{
\draw[-left to,shorten >=2pt](r3)..controls +(60:5mm)and+(40:5mm)..(r4);
\draw[-right to,shorten >=2pt](r3)..controls +(120:5mm)and+(north:5mm)..(r2a);
\draw[-left to,shorten >=2pt](r1)..controls +(45:15mm)and+(north:5mm)..(r2b);
}
\end{document}
```

Note: Atm, the arrow corresponds to the third "\draw" command and starts in the middle of the "Rad" and points up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uncluttered the code a bit.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

% this is the position of the current electron being drawn with a dot
\makeatletter
\def\electrondotposition%
  {\CF@lewis@x pt+\CF@lewis@xoffset*\CF@lewis@current@offset,%
   \CF@lewis@y pt+\CF@lewis@yoffset*\CF@lewis@current@offset}
\makeatother

% hijacking the lewis style to insert a coordinate for later reference
\setlewis{0.2ex}{1.5ex}% these are just defaults
  {red,insert path={coordinate (lastelectrondot) at (\electrondotposition)}}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemfig{@{r1}\lewis{0.,Rad}} \+
\chemfig%
  {R^1(-[@{r2a}::125,,,,draw=none])%
   (-[@{r2b}::145,,,,draw=none])-@{r4}%
   C(-[@{r3}::90]H)(-[270]H)-O-R^2}
\schemestop

\chemmove[shorten <=4pt]{
\draw (r3) .. controls +( 60:5mm) and +(   40:5mm) .. (r4);
\draw (r3) .. controls +(120:5mm) and +(north:5mm) .. (r2a);
\draw [shorten <=0pt]
  (lastelectrondot) .. controls +(45:15mm) and +(north:5mm) .. (r2b);
}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image: chem's hard]

The coordinate `lastelectrondot` always gives you the exact center of the last electron that was drawn. It only keeps track of the last one because it is overwritten by new ones.

Also, this works only with the *dot syntax* of the `\lewis` command.

A more general solution is possible but it's not straightforward and this is sufficient to solve your problem.